# Confine interface to same properties as another interface

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to `Confine<A, B>` an interface to another interface in that it both `A`, and `B` need to have the same properties.

```
export type Merge<M, N> = Omit<M, Extract<keyof M, keyof N>> & N;
```

```
interface Cat {
  cat: string | null,
  created_at: Date,
};
```

This would be ok:

```
type StrictCat = Confine<Cat, Merge<Cat, {
  cat: string,
}>>
```

This would not be ok:

```
type StrictCat = Confine<Cat, Merge<Cat, {
  name: string,
}>>
```

Comment: What is the definition for `Merge`?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin added

Comment: Do you want `StrictCat` to be a value or a type? From the question, it looks like you want `Confine` to produce a value, because `StrictCat` is a `const`. Is that the intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you turn this into a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  I'm guessing `Merge` is not really relevant (you could just replace `Merge<X, Y>` with its result).  And `const varname = TypeFunction<>` is not valid TypeScript.  Once you fix that, could you be explicit about what you mean by "this should be ok"?  That is, what is the exact type you expect `StrictCat` to be?

All that said, it's *possible* that what you want is

```
type Confine<A, B extends { [K in keyof B]: K extends keyof A ? A[K] : never }> = B;
```

but I don't want to spend too much time fleshing out this answer if it's not addressing your question.  Thanks!

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much. 

One issue with this is that it doesn't allow for deep optional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A has the same keys as B when `A extends B` and `B extends A` so:

```js
type Check<A, B> = A extends B ?
    B extends A ? true : false
  : false;

type Result = Check<{}, {}> // true
type Result1 = Check<{ key: string }, {}> // false
type Result2 = Check<{}, { key: string }> // false
type Result3 = Check<{ key: string }, { key: string }> // true
```

or instead of false you can assign `never` type to be sure that will not be used

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Check%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%3D%20A%20extends%20B%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20B%20extends%20A%20%3F%20true%20%3A%20false%20%3A%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Result%20%3D%20Check%3C%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%3E%20%2F%2F%20true%0D%0Atype%20Result1%20%3D%20Check%3C%7B%20key%3A%20string%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%3E%20%2F%2F%20false%0D%0Atype%20Result2%20%3D%20Check%3C%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%20key%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%20%2F%2F%20false%0D%0Atype%20Result3%20%3D%20Check%3C%7B%20key%3A%20string%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20key%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%20%2F%2F%20true%0D%0A)

Comment: This is not exactly what I want, this will return a `boolean type` I simply want to ensure all the keys are the same in both objects.

Comment: So `Check<{ key: string }, { key: number }> ` should be correct?